# Assembly how to return from a function call when a condition is met

Tags: function, assembly, arm

So I'm learning assembly and I've just learned to create a function I create a label, use BL to branch to the label, then use BX LR to return from the function call.

I know LR stores the address of the PC + 4 bits, the program pointer then moves to the address of the label, then the PC increments though the code until it reaches BX LR and then the PC now points to the address LR is pointing to.

My question is if I have the following pseudo code:

```
func initArr()
    for(i = 0; i < max; i++)
        arr[i] = i
    return;
```

How can I translate this to assembly. As I know BX LR returns from the function, however I want to return once I find out I >= max. Would this work?:

```
.global _start
_start:  
    LDR R1, =A
    MOV R2, #0x00
    BL _initArr

_end:
    MOV R1, #0
    MOV R7, #1
    SWI 0

_initArr:
    CMP R2, #MAX
    BEQ LR  @this
    STR R2, [R1]
    ADD R1, #0x04
    ADD R2, #0x01
    B _initArr

.data
.equ MAX, 10
A:    rept MAX
      byte 0x00
      endr
```

To be more specific:

- Does conditional branches paired with LR work in the same manner BX LR works?
- (optional) is the layout of my code correct

Comment: In ARM mode `BX` can be conditional, such as `BXEQ`. Also, you can branch to a `BX`, or to an epilogue code in general. `BEQ LR` is not valid(*), and even if it were, it wouldn't handle the `X` part (exchanging of modes). *actually it is valid but it just treats `lr` as a label, not as a register.

Comment: I think its the whole "exchanging of models" part that is throwing me, I thought that if LR is being loaded with the location the PC is pointing to +4 bits then surly branching back to that location would return you to the next line?

Comment: or is this more of a format type thing? where any branch takes a label and bx takes addresses?

Comment: You have two (or more) operating states, normally ARM and THUMB. `BX` takes care to switch the mode back appropriately.

Comment: Your pseudocode describes a loop with a termination condition followed by a straight unconditional return, whereas your description and assembly code is an _infinite_ loop with a conditional return _inside_. It's a subtle difference, but it's noteworthy, especially since the former is the more usual construct.

Comment: A more efficient way is to count backwards.  Start with `i = max;` and use `subs r2, #1` and then you don't need the `cmp`.  The return is `bxeq lr` as Jester suggests.  You can update `r1` with `str r2, [r1, #4]!`.  You can unroll the loop easily; but it is not clear what you store to the array.  Assembler and pseudo code differ.